# tomorrow date Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the datetime picker from this site: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker which works fine.

i am trying to get the tomorrow date.

```
 $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({                  
                format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
                minDate: moment()

            });

        });
```

This code works well, but the calendar lets me pick today..
I want it to let me  pick starting tomrrow.

Comment: above posted the link related. 
regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did it !!!
it works perfectly

```
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({                  
                format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
                minDate: moment().add('d', 1).toDate()

            });

        });
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me! Although the format is deprecated now, it should be     `minDate: moment().add(1, 'd').toDate()`